# Understanding a graph of energy conservation with bounded and unbounded motions?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, work

This graph is from the physics undergraduate text "Classical Mechanics by Douglas Gregory".
[image]

Above this graph was the statement:
[image]

[image]

What I didn't understand is- as stated in the under [*paragraph], won't the particle be able to reach x=b in a finite amount of time unless E is tangent to the graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the condition as stated in the footnote (which you don't understand), you need to change the figure slightly to reflect the condition as follows:
[image: Energy Curve]
In the figure, the curve V and the line E meet at point A, and at infinity.

Answer (score 0):

The comment in the book is wrong,, there is no reason why V should be a maximum. Just think of the case of a ball going upwards. V is a straight line and zero speed is reached at the turning point in finite time.